# Installed Dropbox API but nothing gets executed

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox-api

I installed the Dropbox API following the instructions in "Using the Core API on iOS".  Made modifications to AppDelegate .h and .m and my ViewController.  None of the API methods get called:  Here is the code from AppDelegate.m:

```
    //  Dropbox API  (Access Token: zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz)
DBSession *dbSession = [[DBSession alloc]
                        initWithAppKey:@"xxxxxxxxxxxx"
                        appSecret:@"yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
                        root:kDBRootAppFolder];   

[DBSession setSharedSession:dbSession];
```

Here is the code from ViewController.m:

```
- (IBAction)didPressLink {
if (![[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]) {
    [[DBSession sharedSession] linkFromController:self];
}
}


- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client loadedMetadata:(DBMetadata *)metadata {

if (metadata.isDirectory) {
    NSLog(@"Folder '%@' contains:", metadata.path);
    for (DBMetadata *file in metadata.contents) {
        NSLog(@"    %@", file.filename);
    }
}
}

- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client loadMetadataFailedWithError:(NSError *)error {

NSLog(@"Error loading metadata: %@", error);
}


- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client loadedFile:(NSString *)localPath contentType:(NSString *)contentType metadata:(DBMetadata *)metadata {

NSLog(@"File loaded into path: %@", localPath);
}

- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client loadFileFailedWithError:(NSError *)error {

NSLog(@"There was an error loading the file: %@", error);
}


//#pragma mark - aImportTABDelimitedFile
- (IBAction)aImportFIle:(UIButton *)sender {

//  dropbox stuff
if (![[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]) {
    [[DBSession sharedSession] linkFromController:self];
}

//  set documentsPath -> DROPItTOme path in Dropbox
NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

//  list documents in Folder
[self.restClient loadMetadata:@"/"];

//  download file
[self.restClient loadFile:@"https://www.dropbox.com/sh/<pathName>=0"
                 intoPath:documentsPath];
```

The x's, y's, z's and path name are all correct.  What I'm trying to do is get a list of files in the DROPitTOme folder, which has 1 .txt file in it.  I do NOT have the didPressLink connected to any button; instead I moved the code to the -aImportFile method, which DOES have a button that I clicked (using debugger and simulator).  Being a noob with the Dropbox API, I don't have a clue what is wrong.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are a few things that can cause your delegate methods to not get called:
1. Your rest client is nil or is being released (e.g., by ARC) prematurely.
2. You're making the call in a background thread that doesn't have a run loop.
3. Your delegate method that should be called back has a typo in it. Unfortunately the SDK doesn't warn you if it can't find a delegate method to call; it just completes without telling anyone.

Comment: Also, the path (the first argument) you give to loadFile should be the remote path, relative to the authorized Dropbox folder itself, and not a URL. (I.e., it should look something like "/folder/file.txt".)

Comment: Also, make sure (if you do have a rest client) that you've set its delegate properly. E.g. `self.restClient.delegate = self;`

Comment: Greg: which delegate method has the typo? and restClient is valid (nonatomic, strong)

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that one of them definitely does, just that that's one way this could happen. I don't see any typos in the posted code.

Comment: I decided to give Chooser a try, rather than Dropbox API, and it doesn't work correctly; I have two Dropbox accounts: 1 personal and the other business.  I have everything set for business (using the business app id), but it only shows personal.  Does Chooser not support multiple accounts?

Comment: DBChooser works!  Now all I have to do is figure out how to get the file downloaded into my app!  :D